# How to check for '\n' using scanf

Tags: c

Apologies C noob here,

I am trying to validate user input from stdin but cant find a way to handle a single `\n` input. To completely simplify the problem I wrote the below. When `\n` is entered `scanf` finishes, if this is the first character entered e.g A user hits enter straight away, `6` will be output by the `printf` statement.

```
int main(){
    char x[6];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", x);
    printf("%i\n", strlen(x));
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is I cant find a way of telling if a user entered a `\n` or 6 legitimate characters. I would also like to set a MAX input check and Im not sure if `scanf` is the write function to take user input with in this case or `fgets` may be better suited.

Comment: Use [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

Comment: Note that `"%[^\n]s"` is not a valid format specifier. You read a string with `"%[^\n]"` or with `"%s"` but yours is a hybrid.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is valid; it's the `%[` specifier followed by matching an `s`

Comment: @M.M the `s` is not part of the format specifier `%[]` and I am confident that the intention is not to match an `'s'`. It's a frequent mistake seen.

Comment: Just don't.  As a self-describe "C noob", you should seriously consider not using scanf at all.  Ever.  It is hard for beginners to grasp, and difficult to use well.  You will spend more time learning the foibles of the scanf language than you will learning C.  You will learn far more if you just use `fread` or `fgets` and parse the data yourself.

Comment: scanf may have served a purpose 30 years ago, but IMO it no longer has a reason to exist.  If you have an application where scanf might be used, you probably shouldn't be writing it in C at all.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%[^\n]s", x);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to determine if the operation was successful.  The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format specifier' operations  2) when using '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  This is because those format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: Note: 'x' is only 6 characters long, so the max number of characters that the user can input (without a buffer overflow) is 5 characters.  The `scanf()` statement should be: `if( scanf( "%5[^\n]", x ) != 1 ) { handle error }`  One possible error is the user's first character is a '\n'

Comment: regarding: `printf("%i\n", strlen(x));`  if the user only entered a '\n' Then this statement will output `0`.  Of course, the code should have been checking the returned value from `scanf()` and never bothered to call this statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getchar()` to check each individual input character and stop taking in input when the input size is 6 or the user enter `\n`.

**Edit:**  I've updated my code according to @chux's suggestion. You should increase the array size to 7 so that the last character can be the null terminator when the input exceeds 6 characters. I also used an int variable `c` to store return values from `getchar` instead of storing directly to x[i] so that it can identify `EOF`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char x[7];
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < 6 && (c=getchar()) != EOF) {
       x[i] = c;
       if (x[i] == '\n') {
           break;
       }
       ++i; 
    }
    x[i] = '\0'; // null-terminate string
    printf("%s\n", x);
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like getchar() for this, it gives you total control.

Comment: @chux Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my answer to avoid the issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> When \n is entered scanf finishes, if this is the first character entered e.g A user hits enter straight away, 6 will be output by the printf statement.

Undefined behavior.  Nothing was read into uninitialized `x[]`, so `strlen(x)` is UB.

---

`scanf("%[^\n]s", x);` lacks width protection.  It has no check of return value. Detecting a `'\n'` only is not trivial.

Use `fgets()`.

```
int main(){
  // char x[6];
  char x[7];  // add at least 1 (useful for the \n code may read)
  // scanf("%[^\n]s", x);
  if (fgets(x, sizeof x, stdin)) {
    x[strcspn(x, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential trailing \n
    // printf("%i\n", strlen(x));
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(x));  // use matching specifier
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int islegitimate(int c)
{
    if(c < ' ' || c > 127)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int isfirstNlegitimate(const char *str, size_t N)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; index < N; index++)
    {
        if(!islegitimate(str[index])) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {

    char x[7] ;
    fgets(x, 7, stdin);

    printf("The first 6 chars of the entered string are %slegitimate", isfirstNlegitimate(x,6) ? "" : "not ")
    return 0;
}
```

You can also remove trailing end of the lines chars (\n in linux \r\n in Windows)

```
char *removetrailinglineends(char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *end = str + !len ? str : str + len - 1;

    while(end > str)
    {
        if(*end == '\n' || *end == '\r') *end = 0;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the main question, the code has several issues:

> ```
> int main(){
>     char x[6];
>     // 1. an attack vector: lines with more than 6 characters will exceed buffer size
>     // 2. The s will never be matched, 
>     //      since %[^\n] consumes everything until EOF or \n
>     // the following char can't be 's'      
>     scanf("%[^\n]s", x);
>     // if scanf fails, then x can be uninitialized:
>     printf("%i\n", strlen(x));
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Fixing problems one by one:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", x); // still not good
```

This will read until newline and stop, but still may overflow the buffer:

```
scanf ("%5[^\n]", x); // better
```

This will avoid buffer overflow, by limiting the read to 5 chars. Unfortunately, if the input is long, there is no guarantee that a null terminator will be written at the end. Also, if scanf fails (like in your case) then x will be uninitialized:

```
char x[6] = ""; // fill NUL chars
scanf ("%5[^\n]", x); // better
```

It will work badly if after reading 3 chars, for example, there will be an IO problem.  To combat that sort of issues, check the return code:

```
char x[6] = ""; // fill NUL chars
int n_read = scanf ("%5[^\n]", x); // ok
if (n_read < 0) error...
else if (n_read == 0) newline or EOF...
else /*1*/  x is ready...
```

Note, that instead of initializing `x = ""`, it is probably better to set `x[5] = '\0'` after scanf. I have chosen the initialization option instead, since it was easier to present the answer gradually that way.

Comment: regarding: *// if scanf fails, then x can be uninitialized:*  This is not true, the first character in the buffer 'x[]' will be '\0'.

Comment: @user3629249 you are wrong. Look at https://wandbox.org/permlink/E9hs0afnLJJ9rRgW

Comment: That is why I stated, in my comments that the returned value from `scanf()` needs to be checked.  The referenced example fails to properly check the returned value.  Therefore, the referenced example is 'a very poor example'

Comment: @user3629249 and I have addressed that in my answer